# Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different - Problem occurs on real Device, not on Simulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

After a bunch of lines of code in the Expo/React Native Project, I wanted to test it on my iPhone. The first minute went well, until I got an unexpected Error Message:

> Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

I had the Error during development several times because I stored a NaN somewhere accidentally. So far so good, happy that the Error Message came directly, I knew where to start to get rid of it.

Following is the Error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.]
Stack trace:
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:271:39 in enqueueNativeCall
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:137:8 in fn
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:259:23 in setTimeout
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/rejection-tracking.js:47:10 in <unknown>
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:169:16 in reject
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:211:11 in doResolve
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:12 in Promise
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:98:25 in fn
  node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/build/NativeModulesProxy.js:15:52 in _callee$
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:17 in <unknown>
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:23 in doResolve
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:12 in Promise
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:27 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:8 in <unknown>
  node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/build/NativeModulesProxy.js:10:62 in _callee
  node_modules/expo-file-system/build/FileSystem.js:50:55 in writeAsStringAsync$
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:17 in <unknown>
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:23 in doResolve
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:12 in Promise
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:27 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:8 in <unknown>
  node_modules/expo-file-system/build/FileSystem.js:46:7 in writeAsStringAsync
  node_modules/redux-persist-expo-filesystem/index.js:13:34 in writeFile
  node_modules/redux-persist-expo-filesystem/index.js:26:30 in <unknown>
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:152:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:200:17 in _callImmediatesPass
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:473:30 in callImmediates
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:337:6 in __callImmediates
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in <unknown>
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:314:10 in __guard
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:17 in flushedQueue
```

After starting the App multiple times, the Error occurs more often and after seconds of use. The redux-persist storage is the main problem. I cannot explain why it worked well (and is still working well) on the Simulator and on a real device it doesn't.

I tried multiple storage packages as 'redux-persist-expo-fs-storage', 'redux-persist/lib/storage' and 'redux-persist-expo-filesystem'. None of them did the work.

The redux/index.js file:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import guidelines from './guidelines/reducers';
import global from './global/reducers';
import ExpoFileSystemStorage from 'redux-persist-expo-filesystem';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    keyPrefix:'',
    storage: ExpoFileSystemStorage,
    timeout: null
}
const reducers = combineReducers({
    global,
    guidelines,
})
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);
export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware())));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

The function promiseMiddleware is used to handle the async action creators in redux as below axios is used to retrieve data in actions.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
...
export const FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES = 'FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES';
export const FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES_PENDING = 'FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES_PENDING';
export const FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES_FULFILLED = 'FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES_FULFILLED';
export const FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES_REJECTED = 'FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES_REJECTED';
export const fetchAvailableGuidelines = () => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES,
        payload: axios.get(CONFIG.API.ROOT + CONFIG.API.PATHS.OVERVIEW),
    }
};
...
```

reducers.js

```
import { FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES_FULFILLED } from './actions'
const initialState = () => {
    return {
        availableGuidelines: [],
        ...
    }
}
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_AVAILABLE_GUIDELINES_FULFILLED:
             return {
                 ...state,
                 availableGuidelines: [...action.payload.data],
             }
        ...
    }
}
```

Does anyone have the same Problem or a hint on how to debug my redux-persist storage. The data stored is a large JSON Object. I am sure that all keys have valid values.

Thanks for any advice and help.

Edit: My Guidelines are about 6MB each. If I fetch only one, it does not seem to crash. As soon as multiple guidelines are downloaded, it crashes. I believe it has to do with the storage system.

```
expo: 35.0
redux: ^4.0.1
redux-persist: ^5.10.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fetching this data on every app start and you don't care if this data is persisted offline, I would recommend using `blacklist` configuration of `redux-persist` to blacklist such large states from persisting.

If this state is static and not changing - you could also just write it to a JSON file and use that file as data source then.

Comment: The state is static, I fetch and store the data for each guideline offline using ```redux-persist```. I will try to write it to a JSON file and read them into my ```redux state``` after app start.